# Change homepage logo for each site multisite setup

Tags: plugins, multisite, multi-language, logo

I recently migrated our website to a multisite using sub-paths, and I was trying to change the logo on each webpage `example.com/en` and `example.com/ja`, but this is no longer possible, is there a way that I can change the logo of each site based on the subpath ? or something similar that can lead me to my goal ?
Thank you,

Comment: This should just happen by default? IIRC each multisite has a separate options table and separate media libraries.

Comment: you should be able to visit the `/ja` site, and change the logo the same way you have always done, then go to the `/en` site and repeat the process. Unless there's some sort of automatic feature or code you've not mentioned that doesn't normally exist? Can you clarify? Note this stack is for programmers, if you're looking for user support or advice on using the GUI then you're better asking at the .org support forums

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, I'll try to check again if I can change the logos, the reason I posted here was because I was looking more into a development solution, like changing the functions.php or header.php, since I couldn't find a plugin that can do what I want.

Comment: for a code based solution you'll need to provide more detail of what you want/expected/need, e.g. if you already have all the logos in an asset folder or plan to then you need to mention that in your question. Try to make your question as specific as possible, and avoid ambiguous or open ended questions. You can always create new related questions if you have similar questions on a theme

Comment: Thank you, i have already found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in the "additional css" tab.

```
.logo_new img
{
  content:url("wp-content/uploads/path/to/image/image.png");
  height: 90px;
  width: 220px;
}
```